# Make http cloud function executable only by the project owner

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using http cloud function ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events ) to write documents to a firestore collection:

```
exports.hello = functions.https.onRequest(
  (req: { query: { name: string } }, res: { send: (arg0: string) => void }) => {
    console.log(req.query.name);
    var name = req.query.name || 'unknown';
    res.send('hello' + name);
    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('ulala')
      .doc()
      .set({ token: 'asd' }, { merge: true });
  }
);
```

this is a test. The problem is that, once you deploy and get the link to the function, it is executable by everyone. I would like instead that only I (project owner) can use it . Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Firebase Functions as I've only used the Cloud Functions (equivalent?). Quickly scanning the docs, it appears that there's no obvious way using the Firebase CLI to change the function's identity with [`firebase deploy`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions). Curiously, there is a [reserved environment variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#reserved-names) called `FUNCTION_IDENTITY` which I assume is what needs to be updated (but is read-only).

Comment: So, you need to do two things.... (1) Create a Service Account that has at least [`cloudfunctions.functions.invoke`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/permissions). And, (2) either find a trick to make this the function's identity using `firebase deploy`. Or, use `gcloud functions deploy` which does permit setting the function's identity at deployment using [`--service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--service-account).

Comment: **Caveat** I'm unfamiliar with Firebase Functions and it's always been unclear to me how different the service is from Cloud Functions so I'm unsure whether deployment is fungible like this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to restrict your HTTPS Cloud Function to only a specific "Admin" user of your app.

There is an official Cloud Function sample which shows how to restrict an HTTPS Function to only the Firebase users of the app/Firebase project: [Authorized HTTPS Endpoint sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint).

You need to adapt it to check if the user is the Admin user. For example by checking the userID in the [try/catch block at line 60](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/3515b7f38a3c598cdb20152a263372e81719ecda/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L60) of the `index.js` file (untested).

```
try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
    if (decodedToken.uid !== "<the admin user uid>") {
        throw new Error("Wrong user");
    } else {
        req.user = decodedIdToken; 
        next();                
    }
    return;
} catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
    res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
}
```

The two drawbacks of this approach are:

- Your Admin user needs to be declared as a Firebase project user in the Authentication service
- You hard code the Admin userID in your Cloud Function (you could use the Google Cloud Secret Manager service to securely store it as a configuration value, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#secret-manager)).

---

**IMPORTANT SIDE NOTE:**

In your Cloud Function you call the `send()` method before the asynchronous work is complete:

```
res.send('hello' + name);
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('ulala')
  .doc()
  .set({ token: 'asd' }, { merge: true });
```

By calling the `send()` method, you actually terminate the Cloud Function, indicating to the Cloud Functions instance running your function that it can shut down. Therefore in the majority of the cases the asynchronous `set()` operation will not be executed.

You need to do as follows:

```
admin
  .firestore()
  .collection('ulala')
  .doc()
  .set({ token: 'asd' }, { merge: true })
.then(() => {
   res.send('hello' + name);
})
```

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) as well as read this [page of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) which explain this key point.

Comment: hi Renaud, perfect, thank you. That was what I was looking for ( thanks also for the clarification on the send method =) )